# How to fetch actual users and exclude bots in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am trying to make a command that gives a specific role to every actual user in a guild , excluding bots.
code I have:

```
    @commands.command()
    @commands.has_permissions(manage_roles=True)
    async def maddrole(self,ctx,role: discord.Role):
        guild = ctx.guild
        for member in guild.members:
            await member.add_roles(role)
        embed= discord.Embed(description=f'{role} have been given to all users.',color=discord.Color.red())
        await ctx.channel.send(embed=embed)
```

this fetches everyone in the guild(bots too) . How do I exclude bots and fetch only real users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Member](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=bot#discord.Member.bot) object has a `bot` attribute which will be true if the user is a bot, so

```
for member in guild.members:
    if member.bot:
        continue
    await member.add_roles(role)
```

Answer (score 1):

`discord.Member` objects have a [`bot`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=member%20bot#discord.Member.bot) attribute that returns either `True` or `False` depending if the member is a bot or not:

```py
@commands.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_roles=True)
async def maddrole(self,ctx,role: discord.Role):
    guild = ctx.guild
    for member in guild.members:
        if member.bot:
            continue
        await member.add_roles(role)
    embed= discord.Embed(description=f'{role} have been given to all users.',color=discord.Color.red())
    await ctx.channel.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: your answer did the job but you need to edit and fix indentation in the answer for others who would see your answer in future.